# NumPy Matrices Won't Align in Neural Network

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, neural-network, backpropagation

I've produced a neural network in Python, with my only support being NumPy. In training the neural network, I use backpropagation, which was working smoothly until I implemented the network into my project, designed to predict games of Rock-Paper-Scissors, and after taking data from two games, returned the error: *Matrices do not align* in the backprogagation section. The program itself can be found below:

*Note: Some of the variables are defined outside of this, as I only contain the neural network portion.*

**The original definitions of data and such:**

```
#input data: using MOCK RPS DATA, 0:ROCK, 0.5:PAPER, 1:SCISSORS - sigmoid only outputs values between 0 and 1
input_data = np.array([[0, 0, 0]])
current_turn = []
#also for training, .Transpose flips dimensions
output_data = np.array([[0]]).T

#set number of hidden nodes to be used in evolution
hiddenNode_quantity = 1
```

**The neural network portion:**

```
#sigmoid function converts numbers to percentages(between 0 and 1)
def nonlin(x, deriv = False):
    if (deriv == True): #sigmoid derivative is just
        return x*(1-x)#output * (output - 1)

    return 1/(1+np.exp(-x)) #print the sigmoid function... sort of?

#random numbers help weights
np.random.seed(1)

#create random weights to be trained in loop
firstLayer_weights = 2 * np.random.random((3, hiddenNode_quantity)) - 1
secondLayer_weights = 2 * np.random.random((hiddenNode_quantity, 1)) - 1

for value in xrange(60000): #LEARN XRANGE, loops through training

    #pass input through weights to output: three layers
    layer0 = input_data
    #layer1 takes dot product of the input and weight matrices, then maps them to sigmoid function
    layer1 = nonlin(np.dot(layer0, firstLayer_weights))
    #layer2 takes dot product of layer1 result and weight matrices, then maps the to sigmoid function
    layer2 = nonlin(np.dot(layer1, secondLayer_weights))

    #on last cycle, when weight are as adjusted as possible, put in the current situation
    if value == 59999:
        #add new situation, with what is currently happening to make current prediction with adjusted weights
        current_turn = np.array([[input_data[len(input_data) - 1][1], input_data[len(input_data) - 1][2], output_data[len(output_data) - 1][0]]])
        input_data = np.append(input_data, current_turn, axis = 0)
        #increase size of input_data
        hiddenNode_quantity += 1
        #apply weights to new input data
        layer0 = input_data
        print layer0
        layer1 = nonlin(np.dot(layer0, firstLayer_weights))
        print layer1
        layer2 = nonlin(np.dot(layer1, secondLayer_weights))
        print layer2
        print output_data
        #based on computer's best prediction, decide the winning move
        computer_prediction = layer2[len(layer2) - 1][0]
        if computer_prediction < (1/3): #if computer predicts player move is rock, play paper
            computer_choice = "p"
        elif (computer_prediction > (1/3)) and (computer_prediction < (2/3)): #predict: paper, play: scissors
            computer_choice = "s"
        else:
            computer_choice = "r"
    else:
        #check computer predicted result against actual data
        layer2_error = output_data - layer2

        #if value is a factor of 30,000, so two times (out of 60,000),
        #print how far off the predicted value was from the data
        if value % 30000 == 0:
            print "Error:" + str(np.mean(np.abs(layer2_error))) #average error

        #find out how much to re-adjust weights based on how far off and how confident the estimate
        layer2_change = layer2_error * nonlin(layer2, deriv = True)

        #find out how layer1 led to error in layer 2, to attack root of problem
```

**layer1_error = layer2_change.dot(secondLayer_weights.T)**

```
#^^sends error on layer2 backwards across weights(dividing) to find original error: BACKPROPAGATION

        #same thing as layer2 change, change based on accuracy and confidence
        layer1_change = layer1_error * nonlin(layer1, deriv=True)

        #modify weights based on multiplication of error between two layers, the multiply by 5 is to accelerate search for global minima
        secondLayer_weights += (5 * (layer1.T.dot(layer2_change)))                #and get out of local minima
        firstLayer_weights += (5 * (layer0.T.dot(layer1_change)))

#COMPUTER NEURAL NETWORK END

#human input selection
human_choice = raw_input("Human Choice: ")
while human_choice not in move_possibilities: #player picked an option other than "r", "p", "s"
    human_choice = raw_input("Please select type 'r', 'p', or 's':")
#add human choice as new information to output data
if human_choice == "r":
    output_data = np.append(output_data, ([0]))
elif human_choice == "p":
    output_data = np.append(output_data, ([0.5]))
elif human_choice == "s":
    output_data = np.append(output_data, ([1]))
```

The "for value in xrange" portion involves the training of the neural network as well as the portion that, on the last cycle of the training, plugs in the value that needs to be predicted.

**However, the bold portion that separates the code midway through is what draws the error.** It contains two simple matrices that are used throughout the entirety of the code, yet the second time the code runs, for the next game to be played, it draws an error that the "matrices are not aligned", as shown below:
[image]

This error has ceased my production. **Are there any possible correction to remedy this?**

Comment: Your question includes a lot of code, but doesn't clearly state the most crucial information - what are the shapes of `layer2_change` and `secondLayer_weights` when the `ValueError` occurs? Given the input parameters you've specified, `layer2_change.shape` and `secondLayer_weights.shape` should both be `(1, 1)` and the dot product should work. I can't reproduce the error with the code you've given above.

Comment: Also, you should always include the *full traceback* for the error in your question, not just the last line, and you should paste it in as *text* rather than an image.

Comment: @ali_m I sincerely appreciate your feedback. Unfortunately, the software I was using did not have a debugger, but I'll be sure to download some immediately.

Comment: I would test the shape of `layer2_change` as it iterates  (assuming that `secondLayer_weights` doesn't change).  I usually don't bother with a debugger.  Instead I just throw in some temporary `print ....shape` statements.